# ArcPy Clip Raster ERROR 000964: Specified extent is invalid

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, raster, clip

I am trying to write an ArcGIS script, however, I can't seem to get Clip Raster to cooperate. This is what I have so far:

```
import arcpy, math

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inDEM = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    points = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    bufferSize = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

    arcpy.AddMessage("Creating buffer...\n")
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(points, "bufferOutput", bufferSize + " meters", dissolve_option = "ALL")

    arcpy.AddMessage("Projecting buffer...\n")
    arcpy.Project_management("bufferOutput", "bufferProject", arcpy.Describe(inDEM).SpatialReference)

    arcpy.AddMessage("Clipping DEM using buffer...\n")
    arcpy.Clip_management(inDEM, "bufferProject", "clippedRaster", clipping_geometry = "ClippingGeometry")
```

Every single time it throws the following error when it gets to the Clip Raster part.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Research\Scripts\script.py", line 22, in <module>
    arcpy.Clip_management(inDEM, "bufferProject", "clippedRaster", clipping_geometry = "ClippingGeometry")
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 16854, in Clip
    raise e
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 16851, in Clip
    retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.Clip_management(*gp_fixargs((in_raster, rectangle, out_raster, in_template_dataset, nodata_value, clipping_geometry, maintain_clipping_extent), True)))
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 506, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError:  ERROR 000964: Specified extent is invalid
Failed to execute (Clip).
 Failed to execute (script).
```

Now the first thing I checked was the coordinate systems, but they are the same. Heck, even in my code you can see I set the coordinate system to match. And when I run this exact same setup manually in ArcGIS it works without a hitch.

Comment: According to the [ArcPy spec](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/clip.htm), the optional parameter clipping_geometry is a boolean, either set to "NONE" or "ClippingGeometry". I do not believe this is related to the clipping extent layer, which is the second parameter.

Comment: Doh. Nevermind.

Comment: It should be noted that the fourth parameter is the clipping extent layer, not the second parameter. This parameter is optional, so watch out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to figure out what I was doing wrong. Seems I was confused about the input parameters for Clip_management. Hopefully this can help someone else.

```
arcpy.Clip_management(inDEM, "", "clipRaster", "bufferProject", clipping_geometry = "ClippingGeometry")
```

It wasn't clear in the spec, but if you want to use the clipping geometry of an input feature, you have to leave the 'rectangle' parameter blank.

Comment: Exactly what I needed - thank you!